# How to pass json response to jade and loop the results

Tags: json, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to use a node.js application where I am making a post http request. The response is of json format and I need to display it in the jade page. When I try to do so, I am not getting the proper JSON response.

app.js

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
    url: 'my URL goes here ',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    auth: {
    user : 'USERID',
    pass : '****'
          },
    body: JSON.stringify("1": "T1111")
}
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
           res.render('CRUD/singleselect', {
            title: 'Select',
            name: 'You!',
            result: body
  });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Error during select' });
    }
})
```

The actual response is

```
{"ResultSet Output":[{"EMP_ID":"T1111","EMP_NAME":"ABC","DESIGNATION":"ENGINEER","REGISTRATION":"YES"}],"StatusDescription":"Execution Successful","StatusCode":200}
```

singleselect.jade

```
extends ../layout

block content
  .page-header
    table
      thead
    tbody
     table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover.table-condensed
      tr
        th EMPID
        th EMPNAME
        th DESIGNATION
         - var cnt = 1;
      each key, ind in result
        td= (cnt++)+'.'
        td= key
        tr
```

When I am doing so, the response I am getting is something like this

```
1.  {
2.  "
3.  R
4.  e
5.  s
6.  u
7.  l
8.  t
9.  S
10. e
11. t
12. 
13. O
14. u
15. t
16. p
17. u
18. t
19. "
20. :
21. [
22. {
23. "
```

I want an output something like this

```
S.No EMPID EMPNAME DESIGNATION
1     T1111 ABC   ENGINEER
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are setting a string response. You should try this: (Parse it to json and select `"ResultSet Output"` to `results` as you directly loop throught this property.

```
       res.render('CRUD/singleselect', {
        title: 'Select',
        name: 'You!',
        result: JSON.parse(body)['ResultSet Output']
       });
```

I'm a `handelbars` person but I strongly following should work.

```
extends ../layout

block content
  .page-header
    table
      thead
    tbody
     table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover.table-condensed
      tr
        th EMPID
        th EMPNAME
        th DESIGNATION
         - var cnt = 1;
      each record, index in result
        td= record.EMP_ID
        td= record.EMP_NAME
        td= record.DESIGNATION
        tr
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Dave,Thanks for your inputs. But now the response I am getting is [object Object]

Comment: This means you are on right track, just need to modify your `view` accordingly. Give me a minute, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton Dave. Worked like a charm :)